# Finding Laurent series expansion of $f(z)$ around domain $|z| < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

[image]

I am not able to solve this further, this is my approach to the question.
I know that the series will look like in the form of powers of "$z$" and I am also about Laurent expansion of  $1/(1-z)$  for $|z| < 1$.

But here the " $i$ " inside $1/(z+i)$ and so on, is giving me some trouble, can I take it outside the bracket and then apply Laurent expansion for $1/(1-z)$? It will still hold?

Comment: **HINT** $\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}$ if $|z|<1$

Comment: Please use Mathjax. Example: `$f(z)=1/(z+i)$` $\to f(z)=1/(z+i)$

Comment: Thank you, This made it so much easier! I was not aware of this. @ Tito

Comment: @Tito Eliatron -- you mean $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$.

Comment: Uhm, which one is correct? I am confused. @Tito Eliatron

Comment: @uniquesolution is right. $\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n}$.

Comment: @Pinalen Welcome to Math SE. FYI, regarding using Mathjax, please take a look at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Tito Eliatron Ok sir

Comment: @John Omielan Yes, I'll take learn it, Thanks for sharing !

Comment: @Pinalen You're welcome. One other place which has MathJax information, but with this being mostly tailored for beginners, is [Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/602049).

Comment: There is not Laurent series for your case, since the power series includes only the terms of positive degree.